# Sed command not working on a different server

Tags: sed

Sed command is not replacing the contents, does so on a replicated server. Both are runnin ksh.

```
sed -i '/NewValue/s/NewValue/SAPROD/g' AVL_5002760241.GMF
```

This works properly. Replaced all NewValue to SAPROD.

```
sed -i '/SAPROD.*/s/SAPROD/NewValue/g' AVL_5002760241.GMF
```

This also works correctly. Replaced all SAPROD to to NewValue

```
sed -i '/NewValue.*500175852/s/NewValue/SAPROD/g' AVL_5002760241.GMF
```

This does not do any substitution.

Comment: post the contents of your file.

Comment: SAPROD ÑÓèå ÇÔÊÑÇã-åÊãÑÑÉ|500175852| |-966|20141124|20141207|-3| |P|ÈÇâÉ ÓÙÑêÉ ÈæÇÁ Ùäé ÇäÇÓÊÎÏÇå AVLC|0|MiscBC|0|90|0|1|STC_CPS| |355276627|10000| | | | | | | | | | | |1-2NHKYEW|0| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |-2000|00:00|23:59|1|2|2|2| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ^

Comment: Junk characters are Arabic ones

Comment: Not able to understand why this issue should arise, works just fine on a different server.

Comment: Does one of the servers have a GNU sed and the other a BSD sed or so? `-i` without a backup suffix is GNU-specific.

Comment: checked size of sed in both servers, is identical. any other way how to check whether GNU or BSD sed? Using GNU/Linux. Damn, made the code for whole 2 days, have to deploy now and stuck with this issue.

Comment: post the contents of `sed --version` from both servers

Comment: It's the same.GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: did one server's files get processed by Windows, and thus change the line-endings from `\n` to `\r\n`? `dos2unix filename` will fix that. code that works on one machine and not on another is very frequent symptom of DOS-istis. Good luck.

Comment: naah, tried so.sed -i '/SAPROD.*506705356/s/SAPROD/NewValue/g' AVL_5017534612.GMF expected the value SAPROD to change to NewValue. grep 506705356 AVL_5017534612.GMF Result: SAPROD ÑÓèå ÇÔÊÑÇã-åÊãÑÑÉ|506705356| |-1655|20141114|20141207|-3| |P|ÈÇâÉ ÓÙÑêÉ ÈæÇÁ Ùäé ÇäÇÓÊÎÏÇå AVLC|0|MiscBC|0|870|0|1|STC_CPS| |355276627|10000| | | | | | | | | | | |1-GSTIMB5|0| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |-2000|00:00|23:59|1|2|2|2| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ^

Comment: Does it work if you remove the arabic characters after SAPROD? The only hunch I have left is that there's a newline byte somewhere hidden in them, although that shouldn't happen with common encodings. How is the file encoded, anyway? UTF-8?

Comment: The file encoding on the server where it works is: AVL_5002760241.GMF: ASCII English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
The file encoding where it does not work is: AVL_5017534612.GMF: ISO-8859 English text, with very long lines
I do not think it should be a newline issue, coz grep gives me the entire line

Comment: Ah, true. Hmm...the file is not read-only, is it? Grasping at straws, I know.

Comment: naah, it is writable, other sed commands are working except the regular expression one stated above. Do you see a issue due to encoding?

Comment: Not really, since your pattern is plain ASCII. Null bytes, perhaps? But sed should be able to handle that. You could run `sed -n '/SAPROD.*506705356/ p'` to see if the match or the substitution fails, that could help. Can you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: Problem is the match. sed -n '/SAPROD.*/ p' AVL_5017534612.GMF works. sed -n '/SAPROD.*506705356/ p' AVL_5017534612.GMF doesn't work. It is somehow related to the Arabic characters in between.

Comment: Similar commands work on the same server in a completely non Arabic file. Can someon help me how to change the encoding of the file to seomthing that wont affect the Arabic characters and also sed will work as is working on the other server?

Comment: Pattern is ISO-8859 on this server, it is ASCII on the other server where the command works properly.

Comment: Another shot in the dark, then: Try `LANG=C sed -n '/SAPROD.*506705356/ p'`. By the way, do you really want the substitution to happen in every line where a 506705356 occurs or only where it is in the second field? Kinda looks funny.

Comment: I know it is in the second field only, nowhere else. It it is in some other line also, then also need to substitute. The actual regex includes 4-5 fields, gave a shorter version for simplicity. newvalue*productlabel*productid* ...

Comment: I did it, but forgot I was working on Production, does it change on production level or was it just session specific? I do not know earlier value of LANG if I changed something environment specific.

Comment: Run this way (`LANG=C some command`) `LANG` will only be changed for the sed command, not for the surrounding shell. Works for all environment variables.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this works. Let me know a little more what was happening? I seriously freaked out man, I thought I changed some value on Production.

Comment: There's documentation on `LANG` and associated variables [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html); I suspect that `LC_CTYPE` is the relevant part for this. To tell you exactly what sed did that broke, I'd have to know your locale and the encoding of the arabic parts of the file, and even then I'd probably have to dig a bit. In *very* general terms, I suspect it had trouble identifying individual characters in what seemed like garbage in the active locale (utf8?). Forcing the locale to `C` tells it to not bother with all that and work on plain bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Run this way (LANG=C some command) LANG will only be changed for the sed command, not for the surrounding shell. Works for all environment variables.

(Quoting @Wintermute to make a Q/A pair.)